# jqgrid add record using form jquery error y[0] is undefined

Tags: jquery, forms, jqgrid, addition

have a jqgrid all working nicely, am trying to add a new record but after i fill out the form i am getting a jquery error y[0] is undefined

the page i am working on can be viewd at: [Demo page link](http://www.focus-on-plants.com/admin/stokists/index_grid_search.php)

am sure its something to do with the select boxes i have on the form, is something set up wrong in my colmodel?
i am using jquery version 1.4.2

here is my code:

```
myGrid = jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid({ 
        url:'data/stokistdata_s_json.php?q=3', 
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: "POST", 
        rowNum:10, 
        rowList:[50,100,150,200,300,400,500,600], 
        pager: '#prowed2', 
        sortname: 'name_mdt', 
        viewrecords: true, 
        gridview:true,
        sortorder: "asc", 
        rowNum:50, 
        scroll: true, 
        editurl: "data/server.php", 
        caption:"Stockist's and Orchid days",
        colNames:[
            'Actions',
            'id',
            'Type', 
            'Name', 
            'Geo Address',
            'Display Address',
            'Telephone',
            'Email', 
            'website', 
            'lat', 
            'lng', 
            'flag', 
            'description', 
            'active'
        ], 
        colModel:[{
            name:'Actions',
            index:'Actions',
            width:100,
            sortable:false,
            search:false
        }, {
            name:'id_mdt',
            index:'id_mdt',
            width:15,
            align:"left",
            sortable:true,
            search:false,
            hidden: true, 
            editable: true, 
            editrules: { edithidden: true }, 
            editoptions:{readonly:true},
            hidedlg: true,
            key: true
        }, {
            name:'id_etp',
            index:'id_etp', 
            width:90, 
            align:"left",
            sortable:true,
            editable:true,
            edittype:"select",
            formatter:'select',
            editoptions:{value:{1:'Stokist',0:'Orchid Day'}},
            editrules:{required:true},
            search:true,
            stype:'select',
            sopt: ['eq'],
            searchoptions:{value:{'':'All',1:'Stockist',2:'Orchid Day'}}
        },{
            name:'Name_mdt',
            index:'Name_mdt',
            align:"left", 
            width:150,
            editable:true,
            editrules:{required:true},
            search:true,
            stype:'text',
            sopt:['cn']
        }, {
            name:'geoaddr_mdt',
            index:'geoaddr_mdt',
            width:150, 
            align:"left",
            editable:true,
            search:false,
            edittype:"textarea", 
            editoptions:{rows:"3",cols:"30"}
        }, {
            name:'displayaddr_mdt',
            index:'displayaddr_mdt', 
            width:150, 
            align:"left",
            editable:true,
            search:false,
            edittype:"textarea", 
            editoptions:{rows:"3",cols:"30"}
        }, {
            name:'telephone_mdt',
            index:'telephone_mdt', 
            width:80,
            align:"left",
            editable:true,
            search:false
        }, {
            name:'email_mdt',
            index:'email_mdt', 
            editrules:{email:true, required:false},
            width:80, 
            align:"left",
            sortable:false,
            editable:true,
            search:false
        }, {
            name:'website_mdt',
            index:'website_mdt', 
            editrules:{url:true, required:false},
            width:80, 
            align:"left",
            sortable:false,
            editable:true,
            search:false
        }, {
            name:'lat_mdt',
            index:'lat_mdt', 
            width:40, 
            align:"left",
            sortable:false,
            editable:true,
            search:false
        } , {
            name:'lng_mdt',
            index:'lng_mdt', 
            width:40, 
            align:"left",
            sortable:false,
            editable:true,
            search:false
        }, {
            name:'flag_mdt',
            index:'flag_mdt', 
            width:20, 
            align:"left",
            sortable:true,
            editable:true,
            edittype:"select",
            editoptions: {value:{1:'Flagged',0:'No Flag'}},
            search:true,//
            stype:'select',
            searchoptions:{value:{'':'All',1:'Flagged',0:'No Flag'}}//{value:":Both;1:Flagged;0:No Flag"}
        }, {
            name:'description_mdt',
            index:'description_mdt', 
            width:150, 
            align:"left",
            sortable:false,
            editable:true,
            search:false,
            edittype:"textarea", 
            editoptions:{rows:"3",cols:"30"}
        }, {
            name:'active_mdt',
            index:'active_mdt', 
            width:20, 
            align:"left",
            sortable:true,
            editable:true,
            edittype:"select",
            editoptions: {value:{1:'Active',0:'Hidden'}},
            search:true,//
            stype:'select',
            searchoptions:{value:{'':'All','1':'Active','0':'Hidden'}} //{value:":Both;1:Active;0:Hidden"}
        }], search : {
             caption: "Search...",
             Find: "Find",
             Reset: "Reset",
             matchText: " match",
             rulesText: " rules"
       },

        gridComplete: function(){ 
            var ids = jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('getDataIDs'); 
            for(var i=0;i < ids.length;i++){ 
                var cl = ids[i]; 
                be = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' value='E' alt='Edit Location' onclick=\"jQuery('#rowed2').editGridRow('"+cl+"');\" />"; 
                se = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' value='S' onclick=\"jQuery('#rowed2').saveRow('"+cl+"');\" />"; 
                ce = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' value='C' onclick=\"jQuery('#rowed2').restoreRow('"+cl+"');\" />";
                fl = "<input style='height:22px;width:50px;' type='button' value='Find' alt='Find Location' class='findMe' rel='"+cl+"' />";
                gc = "<input style='height:22px;width:50px;' type='button' value='Geo' class='geocodeMe' rel='"+cl+"' />";
                jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('setRowData',ids[i],{Actions:fl+gc}); 
            } 
        }
    });
```

Comment: Could you replace the jquery.jqGrid.min.js to jquery.jqGrid.src.js on your test site?

Comment: thanks for looking Oleg, its now using the src js instead of the minified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the bug which is fixed [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/9fd738fae5d1de97ee6fc25211ed39a6322152fe). You can modify the line 6584 of the jquery.jqGrid.src.js yourself from

```
if(fld && fld[0] !== null) {
```

to

```
if(fld && fld.length && fld[0] !== null) {
```

and verify that it fix your problem. You can look at [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/cancelling-edit-form-fatal-error/#p23322) for some more information. You can use the last jqGrid code from [github.com](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid).